# Composicion de componentes

Tags: reactjs

Estoy buscando la manera que la función declarada sea llamada en el componente varias veces (pasándole props), lo estoy haciendo en `app.js` pero solo muestra el `h1`. ¿Dónde debo iniciar la función para que me tome los valores el componente? ¿dentro de ella?

```
function welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hola, {props.name}</h1>
}


export function App() {
 return(
  <div>
   <h1>Hello 4to Componente</h1>
   <welcome name="Ricardo" />
   <welcome name="Paul" />
  </div>
 );
}
```

Ya esta renderizando a través de `index.js` con

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('four'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que tu función `welcome` sea considerada como un componente debe comenzar con mayúscula, como se muestra a continuación:

```js
function Welcome(props) {
    return <h1>Hola, {props.name}</h1>;
}


function App() {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Hello 4to Componente</h1>
            
            <Welcome name="Ricardo" />
            <Welcome name="Paul" />
        </div>
    );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('four'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="four"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 3):

Te ayudaré un poco con tu problema, para ello primero leamos la [documentación](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) de [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs), y dice algo así:

> **Note: Always start component names with a capital letter.**
>
> React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags.
> For example,  represents an HTML div tag, but  represents a component and requires Welcome to be in scope.
> To learn more about the reasoning behind this convention, please read JSX In Depth.

Lo cual traduce a lo siguiente:

> **Nota: Los nombres de los componentes siempre deben empezar con letra mayúscula.**
>
> React trata los componentes que empiezan con letra minúscula como tags del DOM.
> Por ejemplo,  representa un tag div de HTML, pero  representa un componente y requiere que Welcome esté dentro del scope. Para aprender más acerca de las razones detrás de esta convención, por favor lee JSX En Profundidad.

¿Qué quiere decir eso? que necesitas cambiar la forma en la que nombras tu componente, intenta así:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hola, {props.name}</h1>
}


export function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello 4to Componente</h1>
      <Welcome name="Ricardo" />
      <Welcome name="Paul" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Cualquier duda comenta, con gusto te ayudaré